# Airflow - select bigquery table data into a dataframe

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to execute the following DAG in Airflow Composer on google cloud and I keep getting the same error:
The conn_id `hard_coded_project_name` isn't defined

Maybe someone can point me to the right direction?

```
from airflow.models import DAG 
import os

from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

import datetime
import pandas as pd

from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator

from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators import bigquery
from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1),
}

PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "hard_coded_project_name")

def list_dates_in_df():
            hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=PROJECT_ID,
                                 use_legacy_sql=False)
            bq_client = bigquery.Client(project = hook._get_field("project"),
                                         credentials = hook._get_credentials())
            query = "select count(*) from LP_RAW.DIM_ACCOUNT;"
            df = bq_client.query(query).to_dataframe()
            
 
with DAG(
        'df_test',                     
        schedule_interval=None,                 
        catchup = False,                 
        default_args=default_args
        ) as dag:
    
        
        list_dates = PythonOperator(
                task_id ='list_dates',
                python_callable = list_dates_in_df
                )

        list_dates
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that `PROJECT_ID` as seen in line

```
PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "hard_coded_project_name")
```

was assigned value `hard_coded_project_name` since `GCP_PROJECT_ID` has no value.

Then at line

```
hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=PROJECT_ID...
```

the string `hard_coded_project_name` is automatically associated with a connection id in Airflow and it does not have a value or it does not exist.

---

To avoid this error you can do either steps to fix this.

1. Create a connection id for both `GCP_PROJECT_ID` and `hard_coded_project_name` just so we are sure that both have values. But if we don't want to create a connection for `GCP_PROJECT_ID`, make sure that `hard_coded_project_name` has a value so there will be a fallback option. You can do this by

> - Opening your Airflow instance.
> - Click "Admin" > "Connections"
> - Click "Create"
> - Fill up "Conn Id", "Conn Type" as "hard_coded_project_name" and "Google Cloud Platform" respectively.
> - Fill up "Project Id" with your actual project id value
> - Do these steps another time to create `GCP_PROJECT_ID`
> - The connection should look like this (at minimum, providing the projectID will work. But feel free to add the keyfile or its content and scope so you won't be having problems on authentication moving forward):
>
> [image]

2. You can use `bigquery_default` instead of `hard_coded_project_name` so by default it will point to the project that runs the Airflow instance.
   Your updated `PROJECT_ID` assignment code will be

   ```
   PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "bigquery_default")
   ```

Also when testing your code you might encounter an error at line

```
bq_client = bigquery.Client(project = hook._get_field("project")...
```

since `Client()` does not exist on `from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators import bigquery` you should use `from google.cloud import bigquery` instead.

Here is a snippet of the test where I only created `hard_coded_project_name` so `PROJECT_ID` will use this connection.I got the count of a table of mine and it worked:
[image]

Here is a snippet of the test I made when I used `bigquery_default` where I got the count of a table of mine and it worked:
[image]

Comment: Great! Option 2 worked! Thank you!